# How Can I find partial derivative of integral function with respect to x?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I am  given

$$f(x,y) = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{xy}} e^{-t^{2}} dt$$

For $x, y > 0$

How can I find partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ ?

I am trying to integrate it first but it is something called error function.

So, there must be a way without solving integration.

Help needed!!

Comment: You need to use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Then wouldn't that be e^(-xy)?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $f_x = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial u} \displaystyle \int_{0}^{u} e^{-t^2}dt|_{u=\sqrt{xy}}\cdot \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \sqrt{xy}$

Comment: How did you get the partial derivative of square root of xy?

Comment: That comes from the chain rule since $\sqrt{xy}$ is a function of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any continuous $f$.

Let $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\ dt$.

Then $F'(x) = f(x)$, by fundamental theorem of calculus.

Also $F(\sqrt{xy}) = \int_0^\sqrt{xy} f(t)\ dt$.

Now differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $$I=\int_0^{a(x,y,z)}f(t)\,dt$$ the fundamental theorem of calculus  write $$\frac{dI}{dx}=f\big(a(x,y,z)\big)\frac{da(x,y,z)}{dx}$$ $$\frac{dI}{dy}=f\big(a(x,y,z)\big)\frac{da(x,y,z)}{dy}$$ $$\frac{dI}{dz}=f\big(a(x,y,z)\big)\frac{da(x,y,z)}{dz}$$